# Update missing records in table by copying records internally

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table `tt_auth_itm` (autorization items) with integers `tt_auth_id` (authorization profile ID) and `tt_func_id` (functionality ID) and some other fields.
For each unique `tt_auth_id` (authorization profile) records have to be present for a range of `tt_func_id` (all existing functionalities, not a continuous range BTW).

But some records are missing (colored areas in picture; it lists all combinations of `tt_auth_itm` and `tt_func_id`, two columns at a time):

[image]

I know that for `tt_auth_id`=1 records for all required `tt_func_id` are present.

To insert the missing records for `tt_auth_id`=2 I can do this, copying the other field values from the corresponding `tt_func_id` record where `tt_auth_id`=1:

```
insert into tt_auth_item (tt_auth_id, tt_func_id, other, fields) 
  select 2 as tt_auth_id, tt_func_id, other, fields 
  from tt_auth_itm o where tt_auth_id=7
  and not exists
    (select * from tt_auth_itm i where i.tt_auth_id=2 and o.tt_func_id=i.tt_func_id)
```

Now I want to extend this into **one insert statement for all the other `tt_auth_id` values that have missing records**.
I can't get my head around that. I tried to simply change the above query to:

```
insert into tt_auth_item (tt_auth_id, tt_func_id, other, fields) 
  select tt_auth_id, tt_func_id, other, fields
  from tt_auth_itm o where tt_auth_id=1
  and not exists
     (select * from tt_auth_itm i where (i.tt_auth_id=o.tt_auth_id) and (o.tt_func_id=i.tt_func_id))
```

but that is not sufficient (the subselect is empty), the code needs another level of indirection....

What SQL statement correctly extends my '2' case to the generic one?
Please use generic SQL, because I need it for SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird